# Why OpenGL fog just doesn't appear?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, graphics, fog

This is how I enable fog in OpenGL:

```
float fog_colour[4] = {1,1,1,1};
glEnable(GL_FOG);
glFogf(GL_FOG_MODE,GL_EXP2);
glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR,fog_colour);
glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY,0.5);
glHint(GL_FOG_HINT,GL_NICEST);
glFogf(GL_FOG_START,0.1);
glFogf(GL_FOG_END,100);
```

Every object is in the range 0.1-100, but fog just doesn't appear, what happened?

Comment: If the fog doesn't appear, what does? And what kind of scene are you rendering? Perhaps a fog density of 0.5 isn't strong enough.

Comment: Your fog is completely black. My guess is that the background of your scene is black, too.

Comment: @wormsparty: no, the fog color is white (`{1,1,1,1}` is white and not black).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the GL_EXP2 mode.

If you check the formula for the fog blending factor in GL_EXP2 mode:

f = e ^ ((-density * z) ^2)  (clamped to [0..1])

The fog curve is adjusted exclusively with the *density* parameter. If your range is 0.1-100, I would recommend a density of about 0.001.

Anyway, for testing fog is better to begin first with a GL_LINEAR mode. It's just easier to visualize.